# Bug in time-filtering users by their reputation?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Why is filtering [users according to reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month) working the same, regardless whether one chooses `week`, `month`, `quarter` or a `year`?

Given that this *feature* is also on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter) and [tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year), I'd guess **it's all over StackExchange**? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

These time periods are calculated from the start of the current year.

It is the first week of the first month of the first quarter of the year - so cumulatively these would all be identical at this point.

Therefore, the reputation for this week/month/quarter/year is identical.

Comment: @Scrooge - Thanks Chris, was looking for the right tag name :)

Comment: Oh, I see now ... Oded, thank you for the answer. I just took the (wrong) intuition of weeks/months/etc. It tells I'm new ... and hey, thanks for all the down-votes. :)

Comment: @courteous - The downvotes on meta mean disagreement... the rules here are a bit different.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get even _that_ right ... thanks for explaining.